# C - Encrypt and decrypt a string with AES

Tags: javascript, c, encryption, aes

I'm trying to understand how to use [this c library](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) (**tiny-AES-c**). As a web developer, I'm looking to get an equivalent C code for [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcdfs3oo/112/).

The JS code is straightforward:

```
// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');


console.log("Encrypted: " + ciphertext.toString());

// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log("Decrypted: " + plaintext);
```

Given a message to encrypt and a secret, the code generates the encrypted data and transform the results to a string.

---

My C code:

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t in[]  = "my message";
    uint8_t key[] =  "secret key 123";

    struct AES_ctx ctx;

    AES_init_ctx(&ctx, key);
    printf("ORIG: %s",(char*) in);
    
    // Encrypt
    AES_ECB_encrypt(&ctx, in);
    printf("\nENC: %s",(char*) in);
 
    // Decrypt
    AES_ECB_decrypt(&ctx, in);
    printf("\nDEC: %s",(char*) in);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
ORIG: my message
ENC: ̤�+��5<n]EYK�ظ/����
DEC: my message%
```

I understand that I shouldn't try to print the result as a string, but couldn't figure out how to get similar (to the JS) results, using the **tiny-AES-c** API, plus when I tried using longer messages I got strange results, leading me to think I'm using this library the wrong way.

**Q**: What would be the C code equivalent to the above JS?

Comment: You want to encrypt a string using AES ? is that what the whole question is ? (I am sorry unable to understand )

Comment: No, the question is library specific. thank you.

Comment: I see , Oh well I am not aware of that library

Comment: If you are looking for good security use a well vetted implementation such as provided by the language or platform provider. While the results are the same there may be timing flaws or other side-channel vulnerabilities. Also the lack of padding support for ECB and CBC modes is problematic and null padding is not a good solution. Many solutions use processor AES instructions which are orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Thanks @zaph, the point is I'm using this code in a WebAssembly model, using 3rd party libs are a headache. I'm trying to extract the necessary code only.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: Ah, headache vs security, which to choose—a no-brainer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am the original author of the AES library you reference.

When using ECB and CBC modes of operation, you need to make sure your key, iv and the input/output blocks are all 16 bytes long. You also need to decide on which padding scheme you want to use.

You can use CTR-mode to avoid padding and stop worrying about block-sizes. This generally makes the AES algorithm much easier to use as there are fewer edge-cases to handle.

BTW this is also stated in the project README:

> No padding is provided so for CBC and ECB all buffers should be mutiples of 16 bytes. For padding PKCS7 is recommendable.
>
> ECB mode is considered unsafe for most uses and is not implemented in streaming mode. If you need this mode, call the function for every block of 16 bytes you need encrypted. See wikipedia's article on ECB for more details.

EDIT:

If you extend your arrays so that they are 16 bytes long and zero-pad them (or alternatively, declare them static so they will be zero-initialized automatically), I think it should work for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, It would be great if you could provide a short code example (Please ).

Comment: @RoniGadot [The test code](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/test.c) demonstrates the usage. I don't have much time to spare this week, so I won't be able to help for a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry for being such a new-be, but can I replace the in { 0x87, 0x4d, 0x61, 0x91... with a string?

Comment: @RoniGadot no worries :) Yes you can, but the data will still be treated like a binary array, so make sure the lengths are all a multiple of 16 bytes and pad accordingly (e.g. with zeros). Maybe it's easier to just replace each hex-value with a char, so the input becomes something like this: `{ 'm','y',' ','m','e','s','s','a','g','e',0,0,0,0,0,0}`

Comment: The CryptoJS code uses a PBKDF (password based key derivation function) to create the key and IV. So you will still not get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

As @Morten Jensen suggested, you can use the CTR-mode IE:`AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer`

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t key[] = "secret key 123";
    uint8_t in[]  = "my message";
    uint8_t iv[16] = { 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff };

    printf("Length: %lu",strlen((char*)in));

    struct AES_ctx ctx;
    AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
    AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, strlen((char*)in));
    printf("\nENC: %s",(char*) in); // don't use this string as an input

    AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
    AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, strlen((char*)in));
    printf("\nDEC: %s",(char*) in);
    return 0;
}
```

Remember, printing the encrypted data is wrong, you should go over the output and convert it to base64 if you want to match your JS example.

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. @Morten Jensen is that an accepted usage?

Comment: When using CTR mode care must be taken never to use the same counter initial value and key combination more than once. This turns out to be a common flaw even major players have failed at.

Comment: @RoniGadot sure looks like it :) Be mindful of zaph's advice: never reuse an IV + counter-combination in CTR-mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t in[16]  = "my message";
```

your buffer needs to be a multiple of 16.