# Convert uint8_t array (Hexadecimal) to string in C

Tags: c, encryption, type-conversion, uint8t

**Requirements**

I'm a developer but with near-zero experience with C until a week ago. For a project, I need to encrypt/decrypt source-code/text files and need to use C for that.

**What I did till now?**

I'm using [Kokke/tony-AES-c](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) library for it and implementing it with pkcs7 padding as explained in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/erev0s/4c13a5173b607bcea2a1f273981ccdfc#file-pkcs7_padding-c).

In my code (given below), I have a function `my_encrypt`, which is encrypting contents and returning `uint8_t` array (which contains hex). I need to save it and read it later from a file for decryption. I know how to save a string into a file but how can I save `uint8_t` in a file.

For this, I need to convert `uint8_t` to string but after trying multiple solution, I am unable to do it.

**Question**

How can I convert `uint8_t` array (which contains hex) to string in C.

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CBC 1
#define DECRYPT 0;
#define ENCRYPT 1;

#include "aes.h"
#include "pkcs7_padding.h"

const uint8_t * my_encrypt(char *report) {
    //Initialization Vector
    uint8_t iv[]  = { 0x75, 0x52, 0x5f, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x21, 0x21 };

    uint8_t i;
//    char* report = "my super secret thing that needs to remain that way!";
    char* key = "thisIstheKey";
    int dlen = strlen(report);
    int klen = strlen(key);

    printf("THE PLAIN TEXT STRING = ");
    for (i=0; i<dlen;i++){
        printf("%c", report[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Proper Length of report
    int dlenu = dlen;
    if (dlen % 16) {
        dlenu += 16 - (dlen % 16);
        printf("The original length of the STRING = %d and the length of the padded STRING = %d\n", dlen, dlenu);
    }

    //Proper length of key
    int klenu = klen;
    if (klen % 16) {
        klenu += 16 - (klen % 16);
        printf("The original length of the KEY = %d and the length of the padded KEY = %d\n", klen, klenu);
    }

    // Make the uint8_t arrays
    uint8_t hexarray[dlenu];
    uint8_t kexarray[klenu];

    // Initialize them with zeros
    memset( hexarray, 0, dlenu );
    memset( kexarray, 0, klenu );

    // Fill the uint8_t arrays
    for (int i=0;i<dlen;i++) {
        hexarray[i] = (uint8_t)report[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<klen;i++) {
        kexarray[i] = (uint8_t)key[i];
    }

    int reportPad = pkcs7_padding_pad_buffer( hexarray, dlen, sizeof(hexarray), 16 );
    int keyPad = pkcs7_padding_pad_buffer( kexarray, klen, sizeof(kexarray), 16 );

    printf("The padded STRING in hex is = ");
    for (i=0; i<dlenu;i++){
        printf("%02x",hexarray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The padded key in hex is = ");
    for (i=0; i<klenu;i++){
        printf("%02x",kexarray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // In case you want to check if the padding is valid
    int valid = pkcs7_padding_valid( hexarray, dlen, sizeof(hexarray), 16 );
    int valid2 = pkcs7_padding_valid( kexarray, klen, sizeof(kexarray), 16 );
    printf("Is the pkcs7 padding valid  report = %d  |  key = %d\n", valid, valid2);

    //start the encryption
    struct AES_ctx ctx;
    AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, kexarray, iv);

    // encrypt
    AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(&ctx, hexarray, dlenu);

    printf("the encrypted STRING = ");
    for (i=0; i<dlenu;i++){
        printf("%02x",hexarray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return hexarray;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // File pointer
    FILE *input_file;

    int operation;

    char * input_file_buffer = 0;
    long input_file_length;

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Read command line arguments
    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Make sure proper command params are supplied
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s encrypt/decrypt filename\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Define operation type
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "encrypt") == 0) {
        operation = ENCRYPT;
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "decrypt") == 0) {
        operation = DECRYPT;
    }

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Open File contents
    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Open input_file to encrypt/decrypt.
    input_file = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    if (!input_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: '%s' file fopen error: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return errno;
    }

    // Read contents of file in buffer
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    input_file_length = ftell (input_file);
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    input_file_buffer = malloc (input_file_length);
    if (input_file_buffer)
    {
        fread(input_file_buffer, 1, input_file_length, input_file);
    }

    // Close input_file
    fclose(input_file);

    // We have contents of file in input_file_buffer, let's print them.
    printf("File contents:\n-------\n%s\n", input_file_buffer);

    // Let's encrypt input_file_buffer
    uint8_t result = 0;
    result = my_encrypt(input_file_buffer);

    // Convery result to string.
    printf("main: Encrypted File contents:\n-------\n%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this not an XY problem? If your goal is to store an uint8_t array, you should store an uint8_t array. There's no need to convert that to a string for that alone.

Comment: Hexadecimal strings are a human readable interpretation of bytes. The output of the `printf` statement is in hexadecimals, while the input in the `uint_8` array is binary. So if you put the output of the `printf` in a file then you are done. However, files handle binary perfectly fine; you only need hexadecimals for human consumption.

Comment: Ahh, Let me try storing binary in the file. Will get back with the result.

Comment: OK, to test there are e.g. Posix utilities like `hexdump -C` (or just `hd`) to view the contents of a binary file *as hexadecimals*. Many editors / IDE's also have an option to view the contents of a binary file using hexadecimals.

Comment: I am unclear on what you mean by "uint8_t array (which contains hex)" -- it is an array of uint8_t -- that is, an array of unsigned bytes.  You are assigning them by representing the values of the bytes as hexadecimal in the code, but if you had used 'u' instead of 0x75 the array would contain the same value.

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254710/c-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-with-aes ?